# How to fetch data using with via object in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Actually, I want to fetch data using Model object not through Model facade like mention below.

```
$user = $this->getGuard()->user();
```

Above user is current logged user which is

```
        "id": 6,
        "name": "kuser",
        "email": "kuser@gmail.com",
        "phone": "03345154067",
        "is_subscribed": 0,
        "subscription_date": null
```

But when I try to fetch same `$user` object with its related model like cards, by execute `$user->with(['cards'])->first();` than it gives first record of user table with cards like mentioned below.

```
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "phone": "03056494616",
        "is_subscribed": 1,
        "subscription_date": "2019-10-08",
        "cards": []
```

Above mentioned record which is user object. It is first record of my user table.

Actually, I am **expecting**.

```
      "id": 6,
        "name": "kuser",
        "email": "kuser@gmail.com",
        "phone": "03345154067",
        "is_subscribed": 0,
        "subscription_date": null
```

with its related model cards like

```
      "id": 6,
        "name": "kuser",
        "email": "kuser@gmail.com",
        "phone": "03345154067",
        "is_subscribed": 0,
        "subscription_date": null
        "cards":[] // array of cards those belongs to it.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lazy Eager Loading, you don't have to query for the user again, you already have it:

```
$user = $this->getGuard()->user();

$user->load('cards');
```

[Laravel 6 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: yep its working fine. This is what, I really wanted yesterday. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `where` ?

```
$user->where('id', Auth::id())->with(['cards'])->first();
```

won't that work?

Comment: It works, infact now, I used to fetch this way User::with(['cards'])->find($user->id). But, it has some little bit extra effort so, I try to find better one approach.

Comment: whats the "extra effort" here if i may ask?

Comment: $user->where('id', Auth::id())->with(['cards'])->first();
I think it should be like $user->with('cards') and that's it. Hope so, you got that point.
But anyway it also fair enough.

Comment: You dont wanna use `$user = $this->getGuard()->user();`, you also dont wanna use `where`, script cant assume itself which user you are reffering to

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
User::with(['cards'])->find($user->id);
```